# Hibernate Lazy loading in View

Tags: hibernate, jsf, lazy-loading

I have lets say Entity A with a @OneToMany relationship with Entity B. Therefore I have a List entityBlist; that I want to display on a JSF datatable for each Entity A;

This means that I will have to use a "getter" in the EL expression #{backingbean.entityA.entityBlist}

This will obviously cause an exception. Is the only way to resolve this is to replace the getter with an HQL JOIN Fetch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than call the getter in your view, create a new POJO that is constructed from the entityList and use that object in your view. This way, you can use the lazy load functionality of hibernate.